# Two Columns Grouping Sum

Tags: c#, linq

I have two columns on one list. I want to collect these columns by grouping them. But I could not do the grouping work. I'm happy if you help me.

```
void Main() {
    List<MyList> lists = new List<MyList>();
    lists.Add(new MyList { bankCode = "102 01 001", fCode = "100 01 001", Money = 500 });
    lists.Add(new MyList { bankCode = "102 01 001", fCode = "101 01 001", Money = 600 });
    lists.Add(new MyList { bankCode = "102 01 001", fCode = "120 01 001", Money = 700 });
    lists.Add(new MyList { bankCode = "102 01 001", fCode = "320 01 001", Money = 200 });
    lists.Add(new MyList { bankCode = "102 01 001", fCode = "100 01 001", Money = -100 });
    lists.Add(new MyList { bankCode = "102 01 001", fCode = "101 01 001", Money = 400 });
    lists.Add(new MyList { bankCode = "102 01 001", fCode = "320 01 001", Money = -200 });
    lists.Add(new MyList { bankCode = "102 01 001", fCode = "120 01 001", Money = -200 });

    var myList = lists.GroupBy(l => new { l.bankCode, l.fCode }).Select(l => new
    {
        groupCode = ??,
        plusMoney = l.Sum(k => k.Money > 0 ? k.Money : 0),
        negativeMoney = l.Sum(k => k.Money < 0 ? k.Money : 0)
    }).Dump();
    }
    public class MyList {
        public string bankCode { get; set; }
        public string fCode { get; set; }
        public decimal Money { get; set; }        
    }
```

The expected result I require is 
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaQhh.jpg)

thank you very much

Comment: What do you want to get in `groupCode `?

Comment: I think you want `l.Key` or `l.Key.fCode` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to create totals of bankCode together with totals of fCode:

```
var myList = lists.GroupBy(l =>l.bankCode).Concat(lists.GroupBy(l=>l.fCode)).Select(l => new
    {
        groupCode = l.Key,
        plusMoney = l.Sum(k => k.Money > 0 ? k.Money : 0),
        negativeMoney = l.Sum(k => k.Money < 0 ? k.Money : 0)
    });
```

If you group by `new { l.bankCode, l.fCode }`, you group on the unique combination of both codes. Since the example is the same for all bankcodes, the effective grouping remaining is the same as only on fCode. By `concat`enating the groupby's of each code, you get each one separately as in your example image. Since each group has a string as key, the groupCode is simply the grouping-key.

Comment: How do I do it when I want to add another element to the group? For example when I add an object called the 'month' @Me.Name

Comment: Another `Concat` can be added (before the select) with a group by on month, but if month is a numeric value, it would have to be month.ToString() (or another string representation for the month) for the groups to have the same signature and the concat to be valid.

Comment: Or if you mean you want to group on bankCode *and* month as well as fCode and month, you could alter the individual `GroupBy`'s to include month or add a group by *after* the concat that does an extra group by on month.

Comment: _lists.Add(new MyList { bankCode = "102 01 001", fCode = "100 01 001", Money = 500 ,Month=10});_   
I added an item here for a month. This is a numeric value. I get an error when I try to add.

Comment: Actually these items were there. I gave it by shortening the example so that it was lucid. @Me.Name

Comment: If you add the concat as `l=>l.Month.ToString()` it should work. An alternative version: `var myList = new Func<MyList,string>[]{l =>l.bankCode, l=>l.fCode, l=>l.Month.ToString()}
  .SelectMany(fn => lists.GroupBy(fn)).Select(l => new
    {
        groupCode = l.Key,
        plusMoney = l.Sum(k => k.Money > 0 ? k.Money : 0),
        negativeMoney = l.Sum(k => k.Money < 0 ? k.Money : 0)
    });`

Comment: This month is a separate column. And a int type. Thank you again for your response. I do not want the answer is laconic. If you want to change the question and share it again. @Me.Name